# Insert a value from one cell into another cell from the same record

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can I insert a value from once cell into another cell from the same record for each record in a table, overwriting the original value from the destination?
It's a one time query. Using Sql server 2008

e.g.:

```
origin|destination
------|-----------
1     | A
2     | B
3     | C
```

to

```
origin|destination
------|-----------
1     | 1
2     | 2
3     | 3

update into myTable(destination)  
?
```

Comment: excel has cells. in a database think rows, columns, and tables.  insert=create new row, update=change column.

Comment: I don't know if I undertand what you want to tell me. Is it the semantics you are explaining? As far as I'm concerned, cell is just an English word that gets the message accross in the OP's context. How do you suggest the question would be formulated? As always on SO, you are free to edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
update yourtable set destination = origin;
```

Without a `where` clause, this will apply to every row in the table.